# how to convert XML encoding="tis-620" to utf-8

Tags: iphone, xml, encoding

any idea how to convert this xml to utf-8 ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="tis-620" ?>
<rss version="2.0"><channel><title>Pantip.com : Tech Exchange - IT 

NEWS</title><description>ข่าว IT NEWS จาก PANTIP.COM : Tech Exchange ส่งตรงถึงคุณทันเหตุการณ์</description><link>http://www.pantip.com/tech/newscols/</link><category>News/Technology</category><copyright>Copyright 2007, Pantip.com Tech-Exchange</copyright><language>th-TH</language>
<item>
        <title><![CDATA[Google ยัน ยังไม่คิดออกจากจีนพร้อมเปิดทางเจรจา]]> </title>
        <description><![CDATA[<img src='http://www.pantip.com/tech/newscols/news/image/reuters.gif' align='left'><b>Google ยังไม่คิดทิ้งตลาดจีนพร้อมเปิดโต๊ะเจรจากับทางการกรณีถูกจารกรรมข้อมูล</b><br><br>แม้ว่าในช่วง 2 สัปดาห์ที่ผ่านมาจะเป็นช่วงที่ Google ต้องเผชิญกับศึกหนักกับเรื่องจารกรรมข้อมูลเชิงสิทธิมนุษยชนที่เกิดขึ้นระหว่าง Google และจีน แต่อย่างไรก็ตามเว็บไซต์เสิร์จเอนจิ้นอันดับหนึ่งนั้นก็ยังคงไม่คิดที่จะทิ้งตลาดผู้ใช้ที่ใหญ่ที่สุดในโลกอย่างประเทศจีนและพร้อมที่จะเปิดทางเจรจาเพื่อหาจุดกึ่งกลางระหว่างทั้งสองฝ่าย  โดยตัวแทนของ Google ได้ระบุถึงการตัดสินใจของทีมงานว่าทาง Google ต้องการที่จะหาข้อตกลงที่สมเหตุสมผลและเป็นธรรมกับทั้งสองฝ่าย แต่อย่างไรก็ตามเรื่องที่เกิดขึ้นนั้นเป็นมากกว่าแค่เรื่องจารกรรมข้อมูลธรรมดาๆ อย่างที่หลายฝ่ายวิเคราะห์กัน อย่างไรก็ตามมีการคาดการณ์จากผู้เชี่ยวชาญว่าถ้าหาก Google ได้ข้อตกลงกับทางการจีนและตัดสินใจที่จะตั้งฐานที่ประเทศจีนต่อไป ความสัมพันธ์ของทั้ง 2 ฝ่ายนั้นอาจไม่เหมือนเดิมอีกต่อไป <br><br><b>Source :reuters.com</b>]]></description>
    <link>http://www.pantip.com/tech/newscols/news/190110g.shtml</link>
    <pubDate>Tue, 19 Jan 2010 09:00:00 +0700</pubDate>

    <category>News/Technology</category>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

TIS-620 is almost exactly like ISO8859-11 (except for \xa0, which is `&nbsp;` in ISO8859-11), so either use that encoding in your XML parser, or modify the encoding attribute before parsing.

Comment: how to use specific encoding on NSXMLParser ?

Comment: I do not know. Perhaps that warrants its own question.